# Convert list of XY-coordinates into GeoJSON/Polygon geometry

Tags: json, list

From API-responce I get a long list of XY-coordinates of vertices where each coordinate is separated by comma. How can I transform this list into GeoJSON/Polygon geometry?

> ,"shape":[52.515378,13.377378,52.5154638,13.3774424,52.5158072,13.3777857,52.5158072,13.3778715,52.5156355,13.3780432,52.5155497,13.3780432,52.5154638,13.3779573,52.5153351,13.3779144,52.5149918,13.3779144,52.515378,13.377378].

Approach like replace each second comma with space and convert the list into WKT so QGIS or another GIS can convert this into a polygon geometry?

Comment: Are you open to solutions in python?

Comment: yes. (running the python code directly in the python console in qgis would be perfect).

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to fix some for loops if you need to iterate over a JSON with multiple `"shape"`s. The code looks something like this if it's for executing it in the QGIS python console.

```py
import json

# define json string
json_string = '''{"shape":[52.515378,13.377378,52.5154638,13.3774424,52.5158072,13.3777857,52.5158072,13.3778715,52.5156355,13.3780432,52.5155497,13.3780432,52.5154638,13.3779573,52.5153351,13.3779144,52.5149918,13.3779144,52.515378,13.377378]}'''
crs = 'EPSG: 4326' # set here your coordinate refence system code (e.g. EPSG: 4326)

json_data = json.loads(json_string) # load json
shape = json_data['shape'] # extract the coordinates
coords = [QgsPointXY(x, y) for y, x in zip(shape[:-1:2], shape[1::2])] # generate the points with the QgsPointXY class

geometry = QgsGeometry().polygonize([QgsGeometry().fromPolylineXY(coords)]) # create a polyline and then poligonize it
geometry.convertToSingleType() # convert the poligonixed geometry to single part geometry
feature = QgsFeature() # define feature
feature.setGeometry(geometry) # set features geometry

output_polygon = line = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs={crs}', 'Polygon', 'memory')
output_polygon.startEditing()
output_polygon.addFeature(feature)
output_polygon.commitChanges()

QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(output_polygon) # add layer to map
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea! The xy coordinates just need to be swapped but otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with the coordinates swapped.